# How do I reload my message bundle in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, resourcebundle

Is there a way to reload a message bundle in IntelliJ IDEA without restarting the container (or using an external tool)?

When I try to Update the application, the new values aren't reflected.

[image]

...even though IDEA knows about my resources:

[image]

[image]

[image]
Haven't seen this question posted and just don't know whether there's something wrong with my setup.

Comment: Do you have "Update Classes and Resources" option selected for Update action: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html?

Comment: Yes, photo posted